# Цветок барвинок

Tags: этимология

Растет на Украине такой цветок - барвинок. Но, когда я пытаюсь объяснить друзьям из России, что это за растение, они не понимают. И понятно, название-то украинское, от "барва" - "краска". А есть ли у него какое-то русское название?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Даля такое растение называется *могильница*. Но, вероятно, это не общеупотребительное слово. Вообще-то *барвинок* - слово в русском языке известное. О происхождении слова есть сведения у Фасмера. Оно пришло в русский язык через польский barwinek и, возможно немецкий Bärwinkel, которые, в свою очередь, произошли от латинского pervinca. Думаю, что объяснение слово *барвинок* от *барва* 'краска' - народная этимология. Но что-то в этом есть. А друзьям просто покажите картинку, если они не понимают, о каком растении вы говорите. Сразу всё станет ясно.